# How to get jQuery callback fire return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem getting the return value from jQuery.Callback(), below is my code.

This code generate using PHP:

```
var data = {text : "Invalid input value", callback : "foobar"}
```

Now using Javascript:

```
function foobar(text){
 //Check if empty
 return (text == '') ? true : false; 
}

var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add(data.callback);
var response = callbacks.fire('Hell World');

// I need the return value here form foobar function
alert(response)
```

The code above return jQuery $.Callbacks() object and not boolean. Any ideas or alternative to `jQuery.Callbacks()` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if you should use `callback : foobar` instead?

Comment: @Turtle What do you mean? Can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: @ArunPJohny I need the return value from `callbacks.fire()`.

Comment: that is the code what you have.. my question is why do you want to do that... the callback.fire() returns the callback object... so you can't return a value like that.. so why are you using a callback in this scenario

Comment: @ArunPJohny that is why i ask also for alternative. The return value will be used in formvalidation callback object for validation purpose.

Comment: why can't you just call `var response = data.callback('something')`... also need to change `callback : "foobar"` to `callback : foobar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72719/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-russell-pabon).

Comment: @ArunPJohny I cant modify the PHP code that why i used `$.Callbacks()` because `data.callback` is a string.

Comment: @RussellPabon in this `var data = {text : "Invalid input value", callback : "foobar"}` , change it as I suggest.

Comment: @Turtle I cant change the code in the PHP part data.callback will always be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed the objective was to call a dynamic function whose name was stored in `data.name` so

```
var response = window[data.callback]('somethng')
```